# Calculate P(X > 4). Let X be a discrete random variable with the pmf: P(X) = C * (0.6)^x , x = 1, 2, 3, ...

Tags: probability

I'm not sure I'm getting this right.

So, I figured out C using the formula our teacher gave us which is,

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty q^x = {q\over 1 - q}$

so I then applied that to the problem,

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty c*(0.6)^x =$  $c*\sum_{i=1}^\infty (0.6)^x = c*{0.6\over 1 - 0.6} = c*{0.6\over0.4} = c*1.5 = 1, c = 0.6667$

After finding c, I went to answer the question $P(X\gt4)$ so I started by doing $1 - P(X\le4)$

$= P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4) = 0.6667(0.6)^0 + 0.6667(0.6)^1 + 0.6667(0.6)^2$

$+ 0.6667(0.6)^3 + 0.6667(0.6)^4 = 1 - 1.4507$ which seems very wrong.

I then remembered that x is starting at 1 and not 0, so if I take off $0.6667(0.6)^0$ then I'd get $1 - 0.8704 = 0.1296$. I believe this is the correct answer but I'm unsure if I did the steps right?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Slightly less work is to sum the geometric series from $5$ on, we get $\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{(0.6)^5}{1-0.6}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, didn't realize that thanks

Comment: Usually your strategy (go after the little sum) is best.   With the geometric (and its cousin the exponential) the "tail" probability has a simple expression.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, when I first looked at the question I didn't get that P(X > 4) was just using P(5) like what you showed. I was wondering where's the ending? or "tail" as you said. Yes, I'll be using that instead next time!

Comment: The tail probability $\Pr(X\gt 4)$ is what you are looking for. Sometimes, as in this case, that is easy evaluate directly. Other times, as in $Y$ having a Poisson distribution, to find $\Pr(Y\gt 4)$ we would be best off calculating $1-(\Pr(Y=0)+\cdots+\Pr(Y=4))$.